# PHP Mysql Foreign Key

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have two mysql tables:
1- customers
2- lite_order

customers table columns:
customer_id  primary key and Auto Increment field
Email
hashed_password

lite_order filed contains all the order fields that maybe more than one order belong to same customer and i have many fields. most important ones:

lite_order_id  primary key and Auto Increment field
customer_id i made it as "index" and from the relation view on phpmyadmin i selected this column as the foreign key to reference to the primary key in the customers table.

The problem is when a new customer signs up, his information goes to the customers table, an d he fills an order form that its data should go to the lite_order table i get an error on this step:

```
Error: Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`DB_NAME`.`lite_order`, CONSTRAINT `lite_order_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`customer_id`) REFERENCES `customers` (`customer_id`) ON UPDATE CASCADE)
```

How can i fix this error? i have the customers table working and the customer_id in the customers table have a value now, but i need this value goes also to the customer_id column in the other table once the order form is submitted. and i get this error that!.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.lastinsertid.php

Comment: Can you clarify what you're trying to do?  The comment above and the current answer solve slightly different problems.

Comment: i have 2 tables, and a foreign key in the second table, i want the value of the primary key to be inserted into the FK column in the other table when i insert data into the lite_order table. i think the FK should get the value of the PK automatically right? since i have session enabled and the customer is logged in when using the order form page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By assigning the foreign key "customer_id" into the table "lite_order", you assure a reliability of your data. I mean a lite_order can't be inserted without having a customer.

So you have to insert your customer first, then yours orders.

Depending on what extension you use (mysql, mysqli, pdo), you get the last inserted customer_id by :
-[mysql](https://www.php.net/manual/fr/function.mysql-insert-id.php)
-[mysqli](http://php.net/manual/fr/mysqli.insert-id.php)
-[pdo](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.lastinsertid.php)

Comment: customers table data inserted successfully, when the customer filled the order form, the data of the order form must go into the lite_order table, and this step i am getting the error because the foreign key in the lite_order table is not getting the value of the primary key in the customers table automatically.

Comment: customers table data already inserted, but on the lite order, do i have to write mysql code to insert the customer_id from the customer table to the customer_id in the lite_order table or it will happen automatically?

Comment: You have to specify the `customer_id` in the `lite_order_table`, it's not automatic.

Comment: I have the customer_id column as FK in the lite_order table, my question is, when i use the mysql code to insert data into the lite_order table, how can i write the special code for the PK value to be inserted into the FK column? i need to see an example but don't know where to look

Comment: Ok, you will find an example [here](http://www.hardcode.nl/archives_142/article_278-mysql-last-insert-id.htm). I hope it will help you. Either you get the last insert id with a mysql function, or with a php function.